# How to use regular expressions to extract the upper case and the alpha numeric characters in Python?

Tags: python, regex, dataframe

I'm currently working on a data frame with strings. I am looking forward to extracting the location and the fiscal year as separate columns(series). Is there a way to do it using regular expressions:

```
Filename                      
KATH FY19 nepal
Nepal BIRATNA FY2020
India DEL   FY18
HQ chennai FiscalYear2020
```

Expected:

```
Filename                        Location             FiscalYear
KATH FY19 nepal                 KATH                 FY19
Nepal BIRATNA FY2020            BIRATNA              FY2020
India DEL   FY18                DEL                  FY18
HQ chennai FiscalYear2020       chennai              FiscalYear2020
```

Comment: `chennai` is not equal to `Chennai`. You need some rule(s) for the towns.

Comment: noted and fixed

Comment: At least there are no rules for locations, as @Jan mentioned. If including lowercase only (to match *chennai*) in addition to uppercase only, *nepal* would also be matched by regex, which should not be the case.

Answer (score 0):

With the next regex you can obtain the words that contain a number, you can see the result of it [here](http://regexr.com/56cpe):

```
([A-Za-z]+[\d@]+[\w@]*|[\d@]+[A-Za-z]+[\w@]*)
```

If you want to find only the upper cased words by regular expression you can try the next one:

```
\b[A-Z]+\b
```

In python will be:

```
import re
text = "KATH FY19 nepal Nepal BIRATNA FY2020 India DEL   FY18 HQ chennai FiscalYear2020"    
fy = re.findall(r'([A-Za-z]+[\d@]+[\w@]*|[\d@]+[A-Za-z]+[\w@]*)', text)
loc = re.findall(r'\b[A-Z]+\b', text)
print(fy, loc)
```

Output:

```
['FY19', 'FY2020', 'FY18', 'FiscalYear2020'] ['KATH', 'BIRATNA', 'DEL', 'HQ']
```

But with your example this will be selecting HQ as a place, so I will have a more intelligent approach and use for example the spacy library entity recognition to validate a location or just get it.

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')
doc = nlp(text)

entities = ['GPE']
locations = []
for ent in doc.ents:
   if ent.label_ in entities:
      locations.append(ent.text)
```

Comment: Did this solution fix your problem @ganesh ghimire?

Comment: Not really but i found other way arround it.

Comment: Which solution did you implemented?

Comment: i didn't really use any of the solution. I chnaged few steps in the preprocessing to get different result.